# Meteor document collection on server inserted

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'v been working on a chat recently and i had an issue. Sometimes someone sends an message and i gets inserted but the user dont know if its on server (and the other guys read it).

What im trying to do is like whatsapp is doing to show a "check" on server saved.

My main problem is that i cant intercept the message on server insert (at least with my knowledge). I tried to save first the msg on the client and then replicate that collection to server (it is super slowly and works horrible).

Is there any solution to that already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) callback of insert is called after it is successfully inserted on server so you can see if it was inserted by checking if there is no error.

> On the client, insert never blocks. If you do not provide a callback and the insert fails on the server, then Meteor will log a warning to the console. If you provide a callback, Meteor will call that function with error and result arguments. In an error case, result is undefined. If the insert is successful, error is undefined and result is the new document ID.

Like:

```
Chat.insert({message: 'Hello there!'}, (err, result) => {
  if(!err) {
    //successful insert
  } else {
    //sucks, failed
  }
});
```